# Does "he arrived here one hour ago" mean this person is still there?

Tags: meaning

I'm confused about if this sentence implies the person in question is still there or may have departed already:

> He arrived here one hour ago.

Can this sentence mean both things?

Comment: The sentence implies _nothing_ about the person's presence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence only mentions the person's arrival.

Since his departure is not mentioned, we can't infer whether or not he's still there. It'd be best to just ask if he's still there.

Comment: I’ve changed your answer from “imply” to “infer”.  These words are commonly confused.